# custom tag on EBS volume provisioned dynamically by Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, tags, amazon-eks

I'm dynamically provisioning a EBS Volume (Kubernetes on AWS through EKS) through PersistentVolumeClaim with a StorageClass

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: k8sebs
parameters:
  encrypted: "false"
  type: gp2
  zones: us-east-1a
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

PVC below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: testk8sclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: k8sebs
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

And pod that uses the volume:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: alpine
      image: alpine:3.2
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/var/k8svol"
        name: mypd
  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: testk8sclaim
```

I need to tag the EBS volume with a custom tag.

Documentation mentions nothing about tagging for provisioner aws-ebs, storageclass or PVC. I've spent hours to try to add a tag to the dynamically provided EBS volume but not luck.

Is creating custom tags for EBS a possibility in this scenario and if it is how can it be achieved?

Thank you,

Greg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like at this point in time is not something possible yet.

Found these:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/49390

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50898

Hopefully something will be done soon.

Comment: Update: see https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/issues/333 and https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/pull/353

Comment: @FernandoCorreia could you please share some examples like how to add tags custom tags.

Comment: @DineshKumar If you are deploying the EBS CSI Driver using helm, this is how you would specify custom tags to be added to all volumes:
`helm --install aws-ebs-csi-driver --set 'extraVolumeTags.tagName=tagValue' aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver`

Answer (score 7):

The current approach is to use the AWS EBS CSI Driver instead of the K8s intree provisioner: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html

If you use this new provisioner, you can add default tags using [extraVolumeTags](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/fdb98666fa056862748ca337049f907d7b080e25/charts/aws-ebs-csi-driver/values.yaml#L209), or you can add tags for specific storage classes like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: "examplename" # MUST be lowercase!
parameters:
  csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype: ext4
  type: gp3
  tagSpecification_1: "ExampleKey=ExampleValue"
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Docs: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/tagging.md#storageclass-tagging